# Clearing Search Results when entering new search

Tags: jquery, api, search

I've written a wikipedia search web app and I'm having some difficulty.  I don't have a problem requesting the data from the wikipedia api and displaying them in an ordered way in a div with id="results".  The problem I'm having is to clear the results in that element when I run a new search.  Code as follows:

```
    <style>
  @import: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
</style>

<body class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <header class="container-fluid text-center">
      <h1 style="font-family: 'Monsterrat';">Deep Thought's Databank of Ultimate Knowledge</h1>
    </header>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid box">
    <div class="container pull-lg-left">
      <div class="container-fluid text-center"><h2 style="font-family:'Monsterrat';">Please Enter Your Query/Keyword Below</h2></div>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
    </div>
    <div class="container pull-lg-right">
      <button class="btn btn-info" id="submit">Submit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="random" onclick="Random()"><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="blank" id="randomLink">Random  Article</a></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid spacer">
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid box">
    <span class="text-center" id="results">
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

The Script code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $("#submit").click(function(){
    var searchInput = $("#search").val();
    var apiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='+searchInput+'&callback=?';



    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: apiUrl,
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function(data){


        for (var n = 0; n <= data.length; n++){
          $("#results").append('<a href='+data[3][n]+' target="blank"><br><h1>'+data[1][n]+'</h1></a><br><h3>'+data[2][n]+'</h3><br>');

          //console.log(data[1][n]);
        }
        //console.log(data[3][n]);
      },
      error: function(err){
        alert('Critical Error'+err);
      },
    })
  });

  $("#search").bind('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
      $('#submit').click();
    }
  })

});
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks guys.

--BlackBat023

Comment: add `$("#results").html('');` before ajax .. **OR** it will be better to add it on ajax success callback function before the for loop

Comment: That did it... thanks @Mohamed-Yousef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `empty()` inline with your `append` to always clear the results before you add the new results like this:

```
var rslt = "";
for (var n = 0; n <= data.length; n++){
      rslt += '<a href='+data[3][n]+' target="blank"><br><h1>'+data[1][n]+'</h1></a><br><h3>'+data[2][n]+'</h3><br>';

      //console.log(data[1][n]);
}
$("#results").empty().append(rslt);
```

Here's a demo fiddle of this method combo: https://jsfiddle.net/gn3tq4oc/

Comment: Hey @mjw I tried that before and what would happen is the code would empty the element on every iteration of the for() loop.  So the only results that is shown is the last one in the array.

Comment: That isn't correct, i'm guessing you may have had `rslt = '<a href...'` instead of `rslt += '<a href...'` - first one will overwrite the variable every iteration, += will append. Also make sure the final assignment `$("#results").empty().append(rslt);` is outside of the for loop.